# Why are my collectionview cells not animating?

Tags: swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have collection view cells and I'd like to animate all of them at the same time. Even though I'm using `UIView.animate` the animation does not happen and affine transform happens instantaneously.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var collectionview: UICollectionView!
    var moveText: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate = self
        collectionview.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        collectionview.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        view.addSubview(collectionview)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.moveText = moveText
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: collectionview.frame.width, height: 120)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0) {
                print("Starting animatings")
                self.moveText = !self.moveText
                self.collectionview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    var moveText: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if moveText == true {
                label.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50)
            } else {
                label.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        label.text = "mytext"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        ])
        backgroundColor = .orange
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are animating the wrong thing.

```swift
// adding weak self so the timer will not retain the view controller
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    self?.moveText.toggle() // you can use toggle() on a `Bool`
    self?.collectionview.reloadData()
}
```

Instead, you should try to animate setting the value of individual cell

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0) {
        cell.moveText = self.moveText
    }
    return cell
}
```

Also, instead of using `CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)` you could use `.identity`

```swift
label.transform = .identity
```

Worth noting is the fact that reloading collection view every 2 seconds and animating directly in `cellForItemAt` is very inefficient. You should find another way to pass information to the cell's they should animate the content